How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}={1\over e-1}$?
An answer to an old question led me to notice that apparently (based on numerical calculation)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}={1\over e-1}\tag{1}$$
I thought this could be proved, similar to proofs of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{n}={e\over e-1}\tag{2}$$
by using a theorem like Tannery's theorem or the Monotone Convergence Theorem, or the Dominated Convergence Theorem, to justify exchanging the order of $\lim$ and $\sum$, but I haven't succeeded.
If we write this as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_k a_{n,k} , \quad a_{n,k}:=1_{2\le k\le n+1}\cdot\left({n-k+1\over n}\right)^{n-1}$$
and if the order were exchanged, then we would have the desired result:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k\ge 2}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,k}&=\sum_{k\ge 2} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-{k-1\over n}\right)^{n-1}\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{k\ge 2} e^{1-k}\\[1ex]
&=e\sum_{k\ge 2} e^{-k}\\[1ex]
&=e\left( {e\over e-1} - 1 - e^{-1} \right)\\[1ex]
&={1\over e-1}\end{align}$$
But, for MCT, how to show the monotonicity, i.e. that for all $n,k$, $a_{n,k}\le a_{n+1,k}$?
Or, for TT/DCT, how to show that for all $n,k$, $a_{n,k}\le M_k$ for some convergent sequence $(M_k)$?
Or, is there some way to simply derive (1) from (2)?
(I think it's the mismatch between denominator $n$ and exponent $n-1$ that causes my difficulty.)

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^{n-1} &= \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{k-1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1} \\
&= \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{j}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
where the sum can still start at $j=1$ and not $j=0$ even after we substitute $j=k-1$ because the $j=0$ term is $0$.
Therefore
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1} \;\cdot\; \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{j}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}
$$
where the first limit on the right is $\frac1e$ (it is more or less the standard limit for $e^{x}$ at $x=-1$) and the second limit on the right is $\frac{e}{e-1}$ (by equation (2) in the question).

This is the type of approach I suspected would work (deriving (1) from (2)), but for whatever reason I just couldn't see it. (I wonder if the theorems I mentioned might in fact be inapplicable using the $a_{n,k}$ I had defined.)
